# Executing cmd files in terraforms

Tags: windows, powershell, terraform, elevated-privileges

I am provisioning a Windows Server 2012R2 with terraforms on Vsphere. I have the machine up and running. Now I want to run some .cmd files on the machine via remote_exec of terraforms.

The user is not the Administrator, but in the Administrator group. UAC disabled for the purpose of executing scripts via CLI or powershell.

I have written a runAsAdmin.ps1 which would call my install_software.ps1 which will have all the necessary commands to execute the .cmd files.

**runAsAdmin.ps1**

```
  powershell -noprofile -command "&{ start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -file C:\scripts\install_software.ps1' -verb RunAs}"
```

**install_software.ps1**

```
 cd C:\\gitrepo\\lip-core-devops\\terraform\\system-config\\ims\\scripts
 echo "Installing IMS Base from powerscript"
 Invoke-Item .\Install_IMS_Base.cmd
```

I can run execute the runAsAsAdmin.ps1 on a powershell directly on the machine without admin elevation and everything works as expected.

But when I am executing the runAsAdmin.ps1 from the remote-exec of terraforms, the execution is successful, but the contents of the install_software file are not executed. I tried creating a directory before executing the cmd file.

Terraform part

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
inline = [
  "powershell -File C:\\scripts\\runAsAdmin.ps1"
}
```

the connection is all set and successful. I get success at the end of the script execution.

What I am I missing in my scripts that it is not executed via terraforms but works on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by powershell execution policy?, try running it using the -ExecutionPolicy setting. I have to do this when using VM extensions in Azure.

`start powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File runAsAdmin.ps1`

Comment: I tried `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\\scripts\\runAsAdmin.ps1`as well.

Answer (score 0):

i create server with winrm, than i put some command in powershell

```
like
 provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
           "powershell.exe sleep 3",
```